# Catch all errors when trying to open a txt file

Tags: python, try-catch, typeerror, except

I'd like to catch all errors when trying to open a txt file that doesn't even exist.
This is my code block:

```
def read_credentials(filename):
    try:
        with open(txt_file) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        username = lines[0].replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")
        password = lines[1].replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")
        return username, password
    except IOError:
        print("oops")

read_credentials('login.txt')
```

But I still get the following error:

```
username, password = read_credentials('login.txt')
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

How can I catch this?

Comment: The `except` block implicitly returns `None`, which cannot be unpacked.

Comment: Please, post [mre]. The line of the error (`username, password = read_credentials(systray, 'login.txt')`) is NOT in the code snippet you show

Comment: You need a `try/except` around your call to `read_credentials()`

Comment: Also, the indentation is broken

Comment: If an exception occurs, your function will implicitly return None which cannot be unpacked into two variables

Comment: I edited the code block and fixed the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by wrapping the called function in an if-block:

```
    if read_credentials('login.txt') is None:
        print('oops')
    else:
        print('rest of code')
```